# How to bind ObservableCollection to ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, observablecollection

I created an ObservableCollection to fill ListViev from a database using the entity framework. When I call the fill method, I end up in an endless attempt to fill the collection. I have a model Device_compiexity and Device_category, which are related by device_complexity_id. For them, I created the VievModel, on the basis of which I created a collection that is filled.

My ViewModel:

```
class DeviceCategoryViewModel
{
    TechDContext dc = new TechDContext();
    public int Device_category_id { get; set; }
    public string Сategory_name { get; set; }
    public int Device_complexity_id { get; set; }
    public string Device_complexity_name { get; set; }

    public static DeviceCategoryViewModel DeviceCaterogyVM(DeviceCategory deviceCategory, DeviceComplexity deviceComplexity)
    {
        return new DeviceCategoryViewModel
        {
            Device_category_id = deviceCategory.Device_category_id,
            Сategory_name = deviceCategory.Category_name,
            Device_complexity_id = deviceCategory.Device_complexity_id,
            Device_complexity_name = deviceComplexity.Device_complexity_name,
        };
    }

    public DeviceCategoryViewModel()
    {
        FillDeviceCategories();
    }

    public void FillDeviceCategories()
    {
        using (TechDContext dc = new TechDContext())
        {
            var q = from cat in dc.DeviceCategories
                    join com in dc.DeviceComplexities on cat.Device_complexity_id equals com.Device_complexity_id
                    select new DeviceCategoryViewModel
                    {
                        Device_category_id = cat.Device_category_id,
                        Сategory_name = cat.Category_name,
                        Device_complexity_id = com.Device_complexity_id,
                        Device_complexity_name = com.Device_complexity_name
                    };
            deviceCategories = new ObservableCollection<DeviceCategoryViewModel>(q);
        }

    }

    private ObservableCollection<DeviceCategoryViewModel> deviceCategories;
    public ObservableCollection<DeviceCategoryViewModel> DeviceCategories
    {
        get
        {
            return deviceCategories;
        }
    }

    private static DeviceCategoryViewModel selectedDeviceCategory;
    public DeviceCategoryViewModel SelectedDeviceCategory
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedDeviceCategory;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedDeviceCategory = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In initialization in window I do:

```
DeviceCategoriesPanel.DataContext = new DeviceCategoryViewModel();
```

In XAML I do this:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="447" x:Name="DeviceCategoriesPanel" Margin="392,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="392">
                <Label x:Name="label1_Copy2" Content="Категории устройств" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,410" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontWeight="Bold" Width="188" FontSize="14"/>
                <ListView x:Name="categoriesComponentsLV" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MaxHeight="200" MinHeight="150"  Margin="0,44,10,0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceCategories}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDeviceCategory}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="372" Height="197">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="5">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding Path=Category_name}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Device_complexity_name}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: It makes no sense to have an ObservableCollection when you don't add or remove elements to/from the collection during the execution of your program. Since you create a new collection in FillDeviceCategories, just use a plain List, put make the DeviceCategories property writeable. Also make your DeviceCategoryViewModel implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and fire its PropertyChanged event when the DeviceCategories property and the SelectedDeviceCategory property change their value.

Comment: Besides that, it looks odd that you have a collection of DeviceCategoryViewModel as property of the same class. Is this supposed to be some kind of hierarchical structure?

Comment: @Clemens, I created this class for join DeviceComplexity to DeviceCategory. Maybe I do somthing wrong:)

Comment: @Eugene: What does an "endless attempt" mean? Does your `FillDeviceCategories()` method gets called? Does `q` contain any items? What if you call `q.ToArray()`?

Comment: @mm8, yes it has, FillDeviceCategory calling endless, q has items

Comment: Again, what does "endless" mean? Does the `FillDeviceCategories()` ever return?

Comment: "enless" is mean calling again and again, FillDeviceCategories() return ObservableCollection whis items

Comment: @Eugene: So why are you calling it "again and again"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you new up each devicecategoryviewmodel:

```
                select new DeviceCategoryViewModel
                {
```

It's constructor will run.
What does it's constructor do?

```
public DeviceCategoryViewModel()
{
    FillDeviceCategories();
}
```

That is your problem.

Because FillDeviceCategories has that linq in it which in turn will call FillDeviceCategories for each one it finds.... which in turn will each call FillDevicategories… probably not exactly endlessly because you'll stack overflow or something nasty eventually.

Comment: What do I need to do to avoid this?

Comment: Maybe should I create another class?